# jQuery hide classes based on matched ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="bibletree">
  <p id="gen">Genesis</p>
  <p class="gen">01</p>
  <p class="gen">02</p>
  <p class="gen">03</p>
  <p class="gen">04</p>
  <p id="exo">Exodus</p>
  <p class="exo">01</p>
  <p class="exo">02</p>
  <p class="exo">03</p>
  <p class="exo">04</p>
  <p id="lev">Leviticus</p>
  <p class="lev">01</p>
  <p class="lev">02</p>
  <p class="lev">03</p>
  <p class="lev">04</p>     
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#bibletree p").click(function() {
  $(".gen").slideToggle(400)
});
```

As you can see, I am matching any and all `<p>` tags inside the bibletree `<div>`. I want to know how to only toggle those `<p>` that have the class that is the same as id of the clicked element. So, instead of toggling `.gen` it will toggle `.[id of <p> that was clicked]`. What I am asking for is reminiscent of regex references. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not nest related elements?

Comment: This seems like a useful and semantic place for an ordered list.

Comment: I think `.closest` and also here is the link : http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah `.closest` looks for parents, not siblings.

Comment: @KevinB : good catch. sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/adirip/4/edit)**

```
$("#bibletree p[id]").click(function() {
  $("."+this.id).slideToggle(400);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**
if you want to remove all (unnecessary?) classes you could do:

```
$("#bibletree p[id]").click(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('p[id]').slideToggle(400);
});
```

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/adirip/6/edit)**

```
<div id="bibletree">
  <p id="title">Genesis</p>
  <p>01</p>
  <p>02</p>
  <p>03</p>
  <p>04</p>
  <p id="title">Exodus</p>
  <p>01</p>
  <p>02</p>
  <p>03</p>
  <p>04</p>
  <p id="title">Leviticus</p>
  <p>01</p>
  <p>02</p>
  <p>03</p>
  <p>04</p>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bibletree p{
  display:none;
}
#title{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: This will fail with an error when clicked on a `p.lev` for example.

Comment: @preahkumpii edited to prevent errors using `p[id]` to check for the selector actually has an ID

Comment: I really like the nextUntil solution. Very clean.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#bibletree p").click(function() {
  $("." + $(this).attr("class")).slideToggle(400);
});
```

The simplest way to do this, given the code you already have. This assumes those P elements will only have one class/ and what about the one with no class at all?

Disregard, I read your questions wrong. You want the one WITH the id clicked. The other two answers that just popped up help you there.

Answer (score 1):

Q&D

```
$("#bibletree p").click(function() {
  $("#bibletree > p." + $(this).attr("id")).slideToggle(400)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing your HTML structure:

```
<ul id="bibletree">
  <li id="gen">
    <h2>Genesis</h2> // the tag here would semantically depend on the rest of your page.
    <ol>
      <li>01</li>
      <li>02</li>
      <li>03</li>
      <li>04</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  ... 
</ul>
```

You could then toggle the numbered items like so:

```
$("#bibletree h2").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("ol").slideToggle(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bibletree p").click(function() {  
$(this).slideToggle(400)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D7aWQ/

Answer (score 0):

Some nice solutions here. But all of them will raise errors, when clicked on a p without an id.

This one will fix this:

```
$("#bibletree p[id]").click(function() {
  this.id && $("#bibletree p."+this.id).slideToggle(400);
});
```